# Term for an importance level between "Medium" and "High"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm struggling to think of a name for something which feels to me like there's probably a good word for. In a software project, we have a ranking of "importance" of an element. Our scale currently has five levels of importance, which are expressed as follows, from most important to least important:

- Critical
- High
- Medium
- Low
- Trivial

A case has been raised in which we have a legitimate need to introduce a new level, between the existing "Medium" and "High" levels. My question is simply this:

**What is a good term for expressing a priority or level of importance between "High" and "Medium/Normal"?**

We should be able to use the term to say "This item is *[blank]* priority" or "This item has a *[blank]* priority level" and have it make sense.

The best I've been able to come up with is "somewhat high" or "moderately high", but I'm unsure if there's a better (perhaps even obvious) word or phrase I'm missing here which would express the concept. It feels to me like there's a pretty large gap between something that's of average importance and something of high importance. I'd strongly prefer a single word here, but a compound of two words is acceptable if that's the best there is. Any suggestions?

Comment: Medium Plus.  If your terms were grades (A,B,C,D,F) the grade you want to express would be C+ or C+/B-.

Comment: Medium - a bit more medium - kind of medium but sort of highish - very medium - high but still a bit medium (etc etc).

Comment: Elevated.......

Answer (score 3):

I'd say medium-high. You could also add 'very high' or 'higher' above 'high' and bump 'high' down, but that sounds like it would be trouble. You could try heightened, I'd say a 'heightened priority' would likely lie between medium and high, but it's certainly not unambiguous.

Comment: Seconded. By analogy with "North, north-west, west"

Answer (score 0):

For a single word:

> Critical
> High
> **Concerning**
> Medium
> Low
> Trivial

**Concerning** (adj.)

> Causing concern or worry : creating reason for concern : TROUBLING
>
> *found the latest reports very concerning* [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/concerning)

> Causing anxiety; worrying. [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/concerning?locale=en)